# PyQt/ PySide control widgets' actions from diffreent class or file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I am working on a GUI project that was started as simple but growing in size now. Therefore, I have created multiple classes in multiple files to make the code easily understandable.

What I want is that each class should do specific tasks when clicking a particular button or widget.

Here is the simple app I have created using QDesigner which contains three buttons.

[image]

Here is the code I am trying to implement.

```
#!/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow


class Page2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Keeping this action command within __init__ method does not work
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.on_click_btn2)  # <-- This does not work

    def on_click_btn2(self):
        print("Clicked Button 2")


class Page3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def on_click_btn3(self):
        print("Clicked Button 3")

    def clicks(self):
        """ Calling this function from parent class works """
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.on_click_btn3)


class MainWindow(Page2, Page3, QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        Page3.clicks(self)

        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.on_click_btn1)

    def on_click_btn1(self):
        print("Clicked Button 1")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

My question is why am I not able to do any actions from child class's **init** method?

Here is the content of ui_main.py file that was converted using uic6

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton as PushButton

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(332, 360)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(-1, 45, -1, -1)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.btn1 = PushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn1.setObjectName("btn1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.btn2 = PushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn2.setObjectName("btn2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.btn3 = PushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn3.setObjectName("btn3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn3)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 1"))
        self.btn2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 2"))
        self.btn3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 3"))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That inheritance is completely wrong. You cannot subclass from multiple widget types, if you want to add child widgets use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) or proper containers (such as QTabWidget or QStackedWidget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not derive the `Page#` classes from the `QMainWindow` because it's not a window. Also, it's a bad idea to make a widget class inherit a `Ui_xxx` class generated by Qt Designer, because it breaks the information hiding principle. (What if a name of an attribute in a widget class conflicts with the name of an attribute in the corresponding `Ui_xxx` class?)

So, do like this.

```
...
class Page2Handler:
    def __init__(self, main_win):
        self.main_win = main_win
    def handle():
        print("Clicked Button 2", self.main_win)
...
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        ...
        self.page2handler = Page2Handler(self)
        ui.btn2.clicked.connect(self.page2handler.handle)
        ...
...
```

If your page handlers do not need to maintain some kind of state, it's much simpler to do like this.

```
...
def handle_page2(main_win):
    print("Clicked Button 2", main_win)
...
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        ...
        ui.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: handle_page2(self))
        ...
...
```

Comment: Got your point. However, in my case, I need need to retrieve and update widget information from `Page#` classes. That's why I inherit UI class generated from Designer. In your example how do I do that?

Comment: @sundar_ima, you can pass the main window as an argument. I updated the example code.

Comment: Though it does not give me what I want, it allowed me to reorganise my code effectively. Hence, accepting the answer.